# How can the compile log show in the console while generate patterns?

Tags: origen-sdk

When I use Origen to generate patterns, the log printed into the console is as below. The command is "origen g".

```
[INFO]       3.432[0.358]    || Preprocessing Lnk........PASSED with 0 errors, 0 warnings
[INFO]       3.892[0.460]    || Preprocessing C..........PASSED with 0 errors, 0 warnings
[INFO]       4.022[0.130]    || Assembling...............PASSED with 0 errors, 0 warnings
[INFO]       5.034[1.012]    || Compiling................PASSED with 0 errors, 15 warnings
[INFO]       5.213[0.179]    || Linking..................PASSED with 0 errors, 0 warnings
[INFO]       5.449[0.236]    || Dumping .lst.............PASSED with 0 errors, 0 warnings
[INFO]       5.618[0.169]    || Disassembling............PASSED with 0 errors, 0 warnings
[INFO]       5.634[0.015]    || Code Size: 1948 B
[INFO]       17.329[11.695]  ||
[INFO]       17.329[0.000]   || Pattern vectors: 3787
```

How can the compile log added into it as below. Is there any parameters I can add, like "origen g -x"? Thanks!

```
[INFO]       5.886[0.086]    || Linking.......................[0;32;49mPASSED[0m with 0 errors, 0 warnings
[DEBUG]      5.886[0.000]    || 
[DEBUG]      5.886[0.000]    || Showing The Object Dump:
[DEBUG]      5.886[0.000]    || ---
[DEBUG]      5.887[0.000]    ||   Bin: arm-none-eabi-objdump
[DEBUG]      5.887[0.000]    ||   Flags:
[DEBUG]      5.887[0.000]    ||     --disassemble-all
[DEBUG]      5.887[0.000]    ||     --wide
[DEBUG]      5.887[0.000]    ||     --disassemble-zeroes
[DEBUG]      5.887[0.000]    ||     --source
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, add in your question what you've tried so far, then others can help you to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can see the [DEBUG] output from the 2nd screenshot within your log file, but not in the console, and you want to know how to see it in the console too.

Origen has various levels of log verbosity and the default operation is to capture everything in the log file, but reduce the verbosity in the console output to INFO statements, ERRORS and WARNINGS.

If you want to see the DEBUG output in the console there is a switch as you suspect:

```
origen g my_pattern -verbose
```

You can read more about this and the various log-levels here - https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/logger/